# Elasticsearch Group by query with custom aggregation logic

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two fiends in Elasticsearch

```
URI
BROWSER
```

I want to find all those `URI` which were not hit from a particular browser, say `chrome`
I want to write following query

```
1. Group by URI,
2. find distinct BROWSER set,
3. filter URIs where chrome is not in BROWERS set.
```

return result.

I have compeleted query for 1st step

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "uri_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "uri.keyword",
        "size": 50
      },
      "aggs": {
        "not_hit_by_chrome": {

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am not getting how to achieve step 2 and 3 in this query.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways to achieve this.

### Solution 1: Using Elasticsearch DSL

I've simply filtered the documents not having `chrome` in the `browser` using [`Bool Query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) and post that I've simply made use of two [`Terms Aggregation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) for what you are looking for. That way, it would be more efficient as compared to applying filter on aggregation.

Structure of the query would be:

```
- Bool Query
- Terms Aggregation (Parent for uri)
  - Terms Aggregation (Child for browsers)
```

Note that I'm assuming both your fields 'uri' and `browser` are of type `keyword`

**Sample Documents:**

```
POST myindex/mydocs/1
{
  "uri": "www.google.com",
  "browser": "chrome"
}

POST myindex/mydocs/2
{
  "uri": "www.google.com",
  "browser": "firefox"
}

POST myindex/mydocs/3
{
  "uri": "www.google.com",
  "browser": "iexplorer"
}
```

**Query:**

```
POST myindex/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "browser": "chrome"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "myuri": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "uri",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "mybrowsers": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "browser",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "myuri": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "www.google.com",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "mybrowsers": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "firefox",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "iexplorer",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Solution 2: Using Elasticsearch SQL Access

If you are using xpack and if you would like to achieve this via [SQL Access](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/xpack-sql.html), then your query would translate to simple SQL query as below:

```
POST /_xpack/sql?format=txt
{
  "query": "SELECT uri, browser, count(1) FROM myindex WHERE browser <> 'chrome' GROUP BY uri, browser"

}
```

**Response**

```
      uri      |    browser    |   COUNT(1)    
---------------+---------------+---------------  
www.google.com |firefox        |1              
www.google.com |iexplorer      |1
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: In your result `www.google.com` is still coming. While it has been hit from chrome. Your result should return no `uri` in this case. if you group by `uri` then chrome will be in the set. Basically pre filter is not required here.

Comment: Could you post your mapping. The query works correctly in my local elastic. Notice the filter query I've added, the documents with chrome gets filtered before the aggregation is calculated.